# Race condition explanation in Postgres UPDATE FROM SELECT statment

Tags: sql, postgresql, race-condition

I've noticed that the below query in my web application creates a race condition which causes an inaccurate quantity_remaining amount. My application uses the values in the row returned by this query, and inserts them (along with other data) into a separate table, called `charges`. However, I've noticed that after this statement runs hundreds or thousands of times, the quantity remaining is higher than it should be - I've inserted more rows into the charges table than I've decremented the quantity remaining.

I can't seem to reason what the problem would be as the UPDATE part should execute atomically. I know that there is a race condition when the quantity_remaining is near 0, but I've see problems when quantity remaining is in the tens of thousands and does not approach zero rapidly.

What is the race condition in this query that would cause it return the row from `lro` and not decrement quantity_remaining, with a quantity_remaining not near zero? Note that I'm using **PostgreSQL 9.3.3**.

```
UPDATE reservations SET quantity_remaining = quantity_remaining - 1
FROM (
  SELECT lr.id, lo.base_price, lo.page_price
  FROM reservations lr INNER JOIN offerings lo ON lr.offering_id = lo.id
  WHERE lr.account_id = 'some-id'
    AND lo.type = 'blue' 
    AND lr.quantity_remaining > 0
    AND lr.end_date >= now()
  ORDER BY lr.start_date ASC LIMIT(1)
) AS lro
WHERE reservations.id = lro.id
  AND reservations.quantity_remaining > 0
RETURNING lro.*;
```

Comment: Off-topic: you are not *using* anything from the `lro` subquery. It could just as well be replaced by an `exists()` construct. That would also remove the ugly `LIMIT 1`. And: the `order by` in the subquery is not needed.

Comment: The lro result is used in the UPDATE's WHERE clause and the RETURNING statement.

Comment: I stand corrected. But what are you doing with the returned result tuple?

Comment: I'm using it in the application layer, and then saving lro.id in a row in the charges table I mentioned above.

Comment: IIRC, @Craigringer recently had a locking strategy for this kind of race.

Comment: @wildplasser: You might be thinking of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023050/concurrency-scenarios-with-inserts). This case seems a little simpler, though; the difficulty there was that `quantity_remaining` wasn't explicitly stored anywhere, making it difficult to lock.

Comment: No it was Craig. a repeatable read solved by a lock in a correlated subquery. one or two weeks ago.

Comment: To avoid the race condition, I think you just need to lock the record when you first see it, rather than when you reach the update step. Adding a locking clause to the `SELECT` (i.e. `FOR UPDATE OF reservations`) should be enough. I can't see any potential issues from this statement alone when the quantity is not near zero. Could it be a concurrent update of one of the other fields in `reservations`?

Comment: I understand the problems above when `quantity_remaining` is near zero, but I'm seeing problems when it is far from zero, and the symptoms are very similar to a two-step (non-atomic) decrement - `quantity_remaining` is much higher than it should be. But from what I can tell the query should be fine. This is what is baffling me.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I'm not sure it's relevant in this case.

Comment: @user1054915: I can't see it either. If you reduce it to two processes, running and committing this `UPDATE` in a tight loop, can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've tried recreating by looping the same query with multiple psql consoles on multiple machines and it appears to be fine. It must be a problem in my application code, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks for all the help everyone. I'll report back if I find anything relevant.

Comment: Maybe it's the read commited isolation level being inadequate as opposed to a bug (that's why stricter levels exist).  More context would be welcome: does `insert into charges` happen in the same transaction? Does anything else relevant to this update happen in the same transaction? Do these transactions ever rollback? Can `offerings` be modified by another session during this update?

Comment: @DanielVérité nothing else happens in the same transaction. The `insert into charges` is in a separate transaction. I don't know for certain whether this rollsback or not, but I'm pretty certain it shouldn't as it is the only statement in the transaction and there's no way that I can see it fail.